# Asynctask не вызывает doInBackground

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-asynctask

В одном активити у меня три объекта `AsyncTask`

```
final ContentLoadTask initializeAct = new ContentLoadTask(this);
initializeAct.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
final GetImagesUrlTask imagesUrlTask = new GetImagesUrlTask(this);
imagesUrlTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
final GetComments getCommentsTask = new GetComments(this);
getCommentsTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

один из которых вызывает функцию

```
public void RetrieveImages(String... urls) {
        for (String url :
                urls) {
            PhotoRetrieveTask task = new PhotoRetrieveTask(this);
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, url);
        }
    }
```

Можно ли так делать? Правильно ли это технически? И третий `getCommentsTask` не исполняет `doInBackground`

Плюс я читал что `cancel()` работает не всегда корректно, но так как я понимаю, нужно завершать поток вручную после того, как он сделает то, что мне нужно. И тогда лимит потоков освободится и будет выполняться последний, третий поток

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывать задачу в задаче не стоит. Задачи созданы для проведения работы вне UI потока. И запускать задачу из задачи в этом плане нет смысла. Скорее всего тут и начинаются проблемы.

В подавляющем большинстве случаев вам не надо самому вручную завершать задачу. Если же у вас много чего итеративно и последовательно должно выполняться вне UI потока, то вам лучше вынести всё это в IntentService и вместо вызова нескольких задач вызывать метод onHandleIntent Service-a.

так вам не придётся разбираться с нюансами устаревшего AsyncTask-a + вы сможете легко остановить все процессы, если правильно настроите рассылку интентов для сервиса.

Comment: То есть сейчас больше практикуют 'intentService', нежели 'AsyncTask' и можно смело переходить на него? Не будет ли проблем со старыми версиями Android? API 15 например

Comment: вообще про асинктаски лучше забыть.
сервисы нужны больше для задач, когда необходимо работать без активти. попробуйте лоадеры использовать. в вашем случае подойдет AsyncTaskLoader

Comment: @andreich, с лоадерами по моему опыту тоже беда... У меня так и не вышло во всех нюансах разобраться) В итоге пользую RoboSpice или IntentService. ну и AsyncTask для простых задач, забивая на повороты экрана и полагаясь на кэширование своими силами результатов запросов.

Comment: И что-то я не смог найти пре и пост функции в UI потоке для intentService для вывода прогресс баров

Comment: @Herrgott, ну, тут можно как-нибудь извратиться через rxJava или EventBus или Otto. Ну или действительно попробовать поковырять AsyncTaskLoader. Также, используя сервис, прогресс бар вы можете вообще в уведомлении показывать, вместо UI..

Comment: Я прочитал на английском stackoverflow, там предлагают для прогресс бара использовать экземпляр объекта от класса ResultReceiver и передавать его в intent как parcelable

Comment: Через него уже обновлять бар. Ладно завтра попробую, спасибо за ответ

Comment: Нет в уведомлении не в данном случае. Тут надо прогресс загрузки активити в нем же отображать

Comment: А хотел ещё узнать сразу. Нет ограничений на количество потоков intentService? Или есть

Comment: @Herrgott, по кол-во потоков не скажу, да и вообще зачем их там много? То, что это не UI поток и интерфейс не будет "заморожен" вам не достаточно? Не уверен, что вы об этом, но там каждый вызов сервиса обрабатывается по очереди. Ну и отдельные потоки там ещё создавать... Не уверен, что из этого что-то хорошее выйдет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а я могу объяснить для чего много потоков. Допустим активити парсит страницу с изображениям и я хочу чтобы изображения скачивались асинхронно. Ну вообще мне надо бы почитать чужой код, посмотреть как другие делают

Comment: Один поток, одна задача. Распарсите список ссылок на картинки а их уже отображайте скачивайте спец либами типа UIL